# Identify where $ f(x)= \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{|x|}}$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital, piecewise-continuity

So I am trying to identify where $\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{|x|}}$ and I want some assistance if my my reasoning is right.

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}} ,& x \geq 0 \\
      \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{-x}}\ ,& x < 0 \\ 
   \end{cases}
$$
We know $x\neq0$. We also know that $f(a)$ needs to defined and $f(a) =\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $.

I let $a=2$ therefore $f(a) > 0$ however if you plug $f(a)$ in, it will give a negative root therefore $f(a)$ does not exist and therefore it is not continuous

Now, if $b=-2$ and since $b<0$, we use  $f(x)= \sqrt{\frac{1-x}{-x}}$. Thus, when we plug $f(b)$ which gives use a defined number $f(b)\approx 1.2246$.

If we plug in the limit,  $f(b) =\lim_{x\to b} f(x) $, it will still give us $1.224$.

Therefore, since limit exists and the limit equals to the $f(b)$, I can deduce that $\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{|x|}}$ is only continuous if $x<0$.

Is my mathematical reasoning correct in this case? Thanks

Comment: What if $x> 1$?

Comment: It will still give you a math error

Comment: What is a "math error"? I would start by specifying the domain of $f$. Also, read your first sentence, something is missing.

Comment: I meant if I plug in $x=2$ in the equation, it will still have a negative root

Comment: Plugging in and checking a few values is not a proof. Specify the domain of $f$ first, then give all the points of the domain where $f$ is continuous.

Comment: What @Gary is trying to say, is that whether your function is $ \in \mathbb{C}$ or $\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: $\in \mathbb{C}$ I have no idea what this is

Comment: Is your domain real or complex?

Comment: It is a real domain

Comment: Ok, then also consider $0 < x < 1$. Why would'nt the function be continuous there? Is $\frac{d}{dx}$ continuous over $0 < x < 1$?

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion, nobody invited $\frac{d}{dx}$ to this party.

Comment: @TonyK why? Is he not feeling well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, the expression has to be well defined. This means that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1-x}{|x|} \geq 0 & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
1 - x \geq 0\\\\
x \neq 0
\end{cases}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x\leq 1\\\\
x\neq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Hence the domain of the proposed function is given by $D = (-\infty,0)\cup(0,1]$.

Within such domain, the function $f(x) = 1 - x$ is continuous as well as $g(x) = |x|$.

Therefore the quotient is also continuous.

Since the square root function is continuous and the composition of continuous functions is continuous, we can conclude that the proposed function is continuous as well.

Hopefully this helps!